High parasitic draw
Vehicle is a 1957 Chevrolet with a 502 BBC.  Vehicle electrical system was operating correctly prior to engine removal.  Engine was rebuilt and reinstalled.  Since installation engine will start and run however, there is a parasitic draw that will drain the battery (battery is brand new) from 12 volts to less than 10 volts in 2 - 3 hours when everything is off.  Is it possible for the starter solenoid to drain the battery that quickly and yet when battery is charged to 12 volts start the engine

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I've never heard of a starter solenoid doing as you're suggesting. They should be an on/off device and only passing juice when energized. I'd suggest you get an ammeter so you can figure out where the draw is coming from. There shouldn't be that many circuits in a tri-5, so should be fairly easy to find (at least to my pea brain way of thinking).

A lot of stuff typically gets disconnected and moved around in an engine-out, there are many possible culprits, not just stuff on the engine itself.

A lot of stuff typically gets disconnected and moved around in an engine-out, so there are many possible culprits to your parasitic drain, not just stuff on the engine itself. The starter solenoid is one of the least likely possibilities for this drain, although you could have a drain in the starter system upstream of the solenoid.
The typical method to track down a parasitic drain is (with the ignition off!) to disconnect the negative battery cable, then put an ammeter in series between the negative battery terminal and the negative battery cable. You should get a reading which is a measure of your battery drain. Then you pull your fuses one by one until you see that reading drop to near zero, and you know where your drain is coming from. You then work your way down to what that fuse supplies until you find the culprit.

The observations are more consistent with a dead battery and not something related to charging or draining the battery.
Starter batteries have a frequent failure mode of a cell almost shorted internally. When left alone, the failed cell drains itself down to zero and the other five cells make the observed 10V. When charged, the dead cell receives very little charge and can help starting the engine if you are quick.
